# HTML file input event listener not firing when removing selected file path

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a input type="file" in my html and a change EventListener which works properly. I now added a remove button which basically works like this:

```
function removeFile(){
                            document.getElementById("fileinput").value = "";
                        }
```

Simply setting the value of the file input to an empty string. But this does not trigger the event listener. How can I make this work?

Thanks,
Johannes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you show how your are binding this function to the button?

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester Hi, yes this helped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

run ok

```js
function removeFile(){
                            document.getElementById("fileinput").value = "";
                        }
                        
  document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
    removeFile()
  })
```

```html
<input type="file" name="" id="fileinput">
<button onclick="removeFile()">removeFile</button>
<button id="btn1">removeFile</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem of the event not triggering, I just tried your code.